# What is a convenient way to define a class with a static 2d array (and the size of the 2d array is known only during compile time)?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, multidimensional-array

The sample code below shows what I am trying to do:

```
template<int NX, int NY>
class Array
{
public:
  float v[NX][NY];
};

void main()
{
  Array<10,20> grid;
}
```

The above code won't compile, but it shows what I want to do. We have a class that contains an array, and the array class doesn't know its size until compile time. Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit: I want to write a simple reusable array class. That means I need to find a good way to separate the array size from the class.

I also want the class to be fast (and simple) so it must not be dynamically allocated. That means the size can't be given during run time.

I also don't want to use the preprocesser to define the size because that means I will have to go through the hassle of changing a number somewhere. That isn't convenient enough.

Basically, the class doesn't know its own size until compile time, because that is when the main function tells the class its size.

Edit: The above code is good.

Comment: The only reason that won't compile is that `main` must return `int` -- other than that, it's legal code. http://codepad.org/xKxBH2tJ

Comment: Also, "until compile-time" makes little sense -- what earlier time is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than `main` not returning an `int`, this is legal code and should compile. In fact, on some compilers this will compile without `main` returning an `int`, such as VC++ but [this is non-standard behaviour](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.3).

You can also store the size at compile time so that you don't have to calculate it manually.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int NX, int NY>
class Array
{
public:
  float v[NX][NY];

  int size() const { return ArraySize; }

private:
  enum { ArraySize = NX * NY }; // You can also store rows/cols individually
};

int main()
{
  Array<10,20> grid;

  std::cout << grid.size();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) might fit your needs.